# Is there any way to keep the stores open later?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Right now Nook's Cranny closes at 10pm,which sucks for me because I am usually just finishing dinner and such after work around that time. So I keep having to sell my stuff for worse prices and I miss out on whatever they're selling that day.

In New Leaf I could enact an ordinance to keep stores and things open later so I could actually interact with them. Is there something like this in New Horizons?

Answer (score 3):

Nope, there are no town ordinances in New Horizons. You can, however, set your system clock back a few hours to enjoy a few more hours of sunlight (and store access) in-game.

Comment: It is probably worth noting that doing this spoils any turnips you have - just as a precaution